# Include code from other fiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Say I have created fiddle A and in my new fiddle B, I want to include classes from fiddle A. Instead of using copy&paste inclusion, I would rather refer to fiddle A.

Is it somehow possible to include code from another fiddle?

[edit] I am considering the javascript part

Comment: Fork it.............................

Comment: This question is not too broad. It's pretty specific, in fact, and the asker should accept Samuel Liew's answer. The question title might be better phrased as "How can I create a reference to one jsfiddle from another?", though he says as much in the body of the question.

Comment: It looks like switching to CodePen could get you what you want (I haven't tried it myself): http://blog.codepen.io/2013/05/28/new-feature-use-pens-as-external-resources/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot include a fiddle in another fiddle. This is due to the fact that JSfiddle prints out the script content directly into the generated document. The only option for external use is via [embedding](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/embedding.html).

The right way would be to fork a new fiddle if you wanted to create a new project based on previous work.

Otherwise you could host your shared code on your site/CDN, and include it in the external resources panel.

Comment: But forking will not allow me to maintain the classes in fiddle A in a centralized manner. I am looking for a way that allows me to let fiddle A evolve and at the same time be included into other fiddles.

Comment: JS Fiddle is provided for quick tests/demos, not for things that are actually maintained.