# Is it possible to import the javascript from a jsfiddle as an external resource into another jsfiddle?

Tags: jsfiddle

jsfiddle allows importing external scripts in the *External Resources* section of the sidebar. Would it be possible to import the javascript of another jsfiddle in there?

For example, I could create a jsfiddle named "A" which creates a javascript object and use that object in other jsfiddles simply by importing jsfiddle "A" as an external resource.

I'm not sure how desirable this would be, but I'm curious to know if it is possible to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I've been scouring the web for resource that might help you. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162183/include-code-from-other-fiddle) should help.

Apparently, you cannot do this. As fiddles are only meant to be temporary test for logic without the hassle of setting up folder structures in your personal computer.

Hope this helps.